# SignalR intermittently stops when in Azure production slot

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, azure, signalr

I have a web app in Azure that has 2 deployment slots. One slot is for development purposes; the other slot is for production purposes.

I've made a SignalR hub (self hosted) into one of my controllers. Basically what this controller does is that it is responsible for recording records into my Azure DB. In particular this controller is used to control when a user open(s) and email and/or click(s) on a particular link.

The SignalR hub is used to facilitate sending down push notifications to all of the "connected users".

When I test this out on my development slot; everything works as expected.

However as soon as I swap it to my production slot; strange behavior starts to happen. Either some notifications come; some don't (basically never reach the client); or the notifications come late.

Now I do not know how to solve this issue. I don't understand if my code has any bugs in it or not (or of I'm doing something fundamentally wrong).

I need some help on why this thing intermittently stops; or just doesn't seem to work.

An important note...I've also enabled WebSockets into both of my deployment slots.

Also; the consumer is a WinForm client.

Now this is where I am actually sending down the message (the push notification to the respective ConnectionID):

```
AddToTblEmailEventDB(SentEmail, true, strEventOpen, strRecipientCookie);
//Save is done in this function 
string strBody = Helper.HtmlHelper.OpenJsonSerializer(SentEmail);
List<string> lstConnectionIDsToSendTo = new List<string>();

if (UserHandler.ConnectedUsers != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < UserHandler.ConnectedUsers.Count; i++)
    {
        if (UserHandler.ConnectedUsers.ElementAt(i).EmailAddress == SentEmail.tbl1Merges.AspNetUser.Email.ToString())
        {
            lstConnectionIDsToSendTo.Add(UserHandler.ConnectedUsers.ElementAt(i).ConnectionID);
        }
    }
}
//Actual Sending down happens here below....
if (lstConnectionIDsToSendTo.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lstConnectionIDsToSendTo.Count; i++)
    {
        //Start sending the messages down to the devices
        hubContext.Clients.Client(lstConnectionIDsToSendTo.ElementAt(i)).updateMessages(strBody);
    }
}
```

Now this is the code to basically Consume the message (which is in JSON format) to the client:

```
HubProxy.On(Of String)("updateMessages", Sub(message)
     Me.Invoke(DirectCast(
               Sub()

                If DateTime.Now < dtmHideNotification Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                   strJSONData = message  
                   'Display
                    If strJSONData <> String.Empty Then
                    strJSONData = "[" & strJSONData & "]"
                    strJSONData = strJSONData.Replace(JSON_QUOTE, """") '&quot;
                        dvNotifications = GetNotifications(strJSONData)

                        If dvNotifications IsNot Nothing Then
                            strSubject = dvNotifications(0).Item("Subject")
                            strType = Trim(dvNotifications(0).Item("Type"))
                            strDateTime = (dvNotifications(0).Item("Date"))
                            strRecipient = dvNotifications(0).Item("Recipients")
                            strEmailSendID = Trim(dvNotifications(0).Item("EmailSendID"))
                            If dvNotifications.Table.Columns("LinkClicked") IsNot Nothing Then
                                strLinkClicked = CStr(dvNotifications(0).Item("LinkClicked"))
                            Else
                                strLinkClicked = String.Empty
                            End If
                            If CInt(strRecipient) = 1 Then
                                strRecipient = dvNotifications(0).Item("EmailAddress")
                            Else
                                'strRecipient = "Someone"
                                'Dutt 7/12/15 Instead of someone , displaying "RecipientName or .."
                                strRecipient = dvNotifications(0).Item("EmailAddress") & " or..."
                            End If

                            If (strLinkClicked.Length > 20) Then
                                strLinkClicked = strLinkClicked.Substring(0, 20) & "..."
                            End If

                            Select Case strType
                                Case "O"
                                    strType = "Opened"
                                Case "C"
                                    strType = "Clicked"
                                Case "M"
                                    Exit Sub 'If there is a Merge taking place, then need to skip this iteration of the loop (because we don't want to show it)
                                Case Else
                                    'Do nothing Keep as same
                            End Select

                            Dim CustomNotification As New CustomNotification
                            CustomNotification.TopMost = False
                            CustomNotification.lblSubject.Text = IIf(strSubject = String.Empty, "[No Subject]", strSubject)
                            CustomNotification.EmailSendID = strEmailSendID
                            CustomNotification.pctIcon.Visible = True


                            CustomNotification.UserName = GetUserEmail()
                            CustomNotification.Password = GetUserPassword()

                            If strType <> String.Empty Then
                                If Trim(strType) = "Opened" Then
                                    CustomNotification.pctBox.Image = My.Resources.glyphicons_52_eye_open
                                   CustomNotification.lblContent.Text = strRecipient & " has " & strType.ToLower() & " this " & strDateTime
                                End If

                                If Trim(strType) = "Clicked" Then
                                    CustomNotification.pctBox.Image = My.Resources.glyphicons_51_link
                                   CustomNotification.lblContent.Text = strRecipient & " has clicked on" & " " & strLinkClicked & " " & strDateTime
                                End If
                            End If

                            CustomNotification.ShowDialog()
                            If CustomNotification.CloseTemporarily Then
                                If CustomNotification.CloseTemporarily Then
                                    'Hide the form
                                    CustomNotification.Close()
                                    dtmHideNotification = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2)
                                    Exit Sub
                                End If
                            End If
                            'Next
                        End If
                    End If
End Sub, Action))
End Sub)
```

Note that the WinForm consumer is a VB.NET form; and all it does it connect to the Hub, wait for any of the messages to be sent.

I do not know where this is going wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried turning off ARR Affinity? It's possible that the load balancer keeps sending your traffic to the machine that it initially connected to.

[image]

Comment: I haven't come across this ARR Affinity issue before in the past. But I'll try it now.

Comment: Make sure you remove the ARRAffinity cookie from your browser and turn off ARR Affinity on both deployments then test.

Comment: Just testing this on the development slot right now....I seem to be getting the pushes right now....can't be too sure. Will swap later to confirm.

Comment: It's seemed to have worked. It's working fine on production so far.